# Problems copying to SD card

Tags: files, sd-card, cp

I am trying to automate copying a large file (25MB +) to an SD card, but it's not working - So I've tried in the command line...

```
cp /tmp/MIRROR/myfile.db /run/media/mmcblk0p1/MIRROR/
```

but this throws the error:

> cp: write error: Input/output error

If I `ls`, it appears most of the file has been copied, maybe 24MB or less.

Now, any further attempts to write to the same location (including `rm`ing the copied file) throw a new error

> rm: can't remove 'myfile.db': Read-only file system

I only get this error after the first one fails (e.g. copying smaller files first works fine after which I can still write to the location)

In Windows, the failed file can't be copied from the SD card, (it says it's corrupt), but I can use Windows to format the SD card to try again (formatting as FAT). I also have no problem copying large files onto it in Windows.

What could be the problem here, and is there an alternative way of copying the files that might work better?

**Edit**

I did a `dmesg` and there are a lot of errors in there but most of them are repetitions so here is a sample of the different errors that appear:

> mmcblk0: error -84 transferring data, sector 135, nr 1, cmd response 0x900, card status 0xc00

(though sometimes `card status 0x0`)

> blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 135

> Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0p1, logical block 0, lost sync page write

> FAT-fs (mmcblk0p1): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid cluster chain (i_pos 11267)

> FAT-fs (mmcblk0p1): Filesystem has been set read-only

(I suppose that last one explains the second error)

**Further Edit**

Looks like a problem with the cards alright - for some reason it doesn't work with Sandisk 2GB SD cards (I've tried 3 of them), but it's fine with Transcend 2GB SD cards!

Comment: if you don't have anything on the card that you care about, you could unmount it, format it and then try mounting it and copying again in case the file-system is corrupt.  I have a suspicion that your card is broken though.

Comment: @jad - thanks... tried with another card and have the same problem

Comment: are you able to format the card properly?  is your card reader built in, or a USB one?